# Unit test controller with form validation

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a form with some validation. **How do I unit test the `hasFormError` function.** I use that as a helper for my view.

For example, in my view.

```
  <div class='form-group' ng-class="{ 'is-invalid': exampleCtrl.hasFormError('card') }">
    <input type='text' ng-model='exampleCtrl.data.name' name='name' />
  </div>
```

**the example controller (uses the `controllerAs` syntax)**

```
  var vm = this;
  vm.submitted = false;

  vm.hasFormError = function(field) {
    var isInvalidandSubmitted = vm.submitted && $scope.exampleCtrl.myForm[field].$invalid;
    var isInvalidandDirty = $scope.exampleCtrl.myForm[field].$invalid &&
      $scope.exampleCtrl.myForm[field].$touched &&
      !$scope.exampleCtrl.myForm[field].$pristine;

    return isInvalidandSubmitted || isInvalidandDirty;
  };
```

**unit test**

```
  describe('#hasFormError', function() {
    var form = '<form name="exampleCtrl.myForm">' +
      '<input name="exampleField" ng-model="test" /></form>';
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $compile) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      ctrl = $controller('PlansCheckoutCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      });

      $compile(form)(scope);
      $scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should', function() {
      ctrl.submitted = true;
      ctrl.hasFormError('exampleField');

      // returns TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.example.myForm')
    });

  });
```

Comment: did the answer below work for you or did you figure an alternate way?

Comment: @cusejuice , is the below answer work for you

Answer (score 3):

Try this way.You can validate your form in this way.
There is no need to define function to test the form validity.

```
describe('#hasFormError', function() {

    var $scope,form,templateHtml,ctrl;


    beforeEach(module("hereisyourmodulename"));
    beforeEach(module("views/path/yourformhtml.html"), function () { // views/test/test.html

      });


    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $compile,$templateCache) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        ctrl = $controller('PlansCheckoutCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
          });

              templateHtml = $templateCache.get("views/path/yourformhtml.templateHtml"); //// views/test/test.html
            var template = angular.element("<div>" + templateHtml + "</div>")
            $compile(template)($scope);

            form = $scope.newuser;  // newuser is the form name
            $scope.$apply();

    }));

        it("\n\ncase 1  :    controller  defined \n", function () {
            expect(ctrl).toBeTruthy();
        });

       it("\n\ncase 2 :   here is the validation", function () {
            form.first_name.$setViewValue("RIy*");  //first_name is one of form value
            expect(form.first_name.$valid).toBeFalsy();
        });

  });
```